# chaining multi-parameter functions

Tags: function, haskell

Suppose I have two functions, `f:X->Y` and `g:Y*Y->Z`. 
I want to make a third function, `h(a, b) = g(f(a), f(b))`.

```
h a b = g (f a) (f b)
```

Is there any way to write it like `h(a, b) = g*f (a, b)`?

And what if `h(a,b,c,d) = g2*g1*f2*f1 (a,b,c,d)`, where `g_i` takes 2 args?

Comment: your two examples are out of sync. The first should be `g (f1 a) (f2 b)` or the second `g (f a) (f b) (f c) (f d)`.

Comment: You can write `h = \a b -> g (f a) (f b)` as `h = (. f) . g . f`, but you shouldn't (readability).

Comment: in your new 2nd example, you mean `f` functions taking ` arg, and `g` funcs taking 2? Then you need a 3rd level. Could you write it out in full exactly?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Searching Hoogle for functions with the [right signature](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%28a%20-%3E%20b%29%20-%3E%20%28b%20-%3E%20b%20-%3E%20c%29%20-%3E%20a%20-%3E%20c) reveals [`on`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-Function.html#v%3aon) from Data.Function. According to its documentation,

```
g `on` f
```

seems to be what you want.

Answer (score 7):

The `on` combinator (in `Data.Function`, as pointed out by gspr in another answer) is defined by

```
g `on` f = \x y -> g (f x) (f y)
```

Which would allow you to write

```
h = g `on` f
```

You can make higher-dimensional generalizations of this, for example

```
g `on3` f = \x y z -> g (f x) (f y) (f z)

g `on4` f = \w x y z -> g (f w) (f x) (f y) (f z)
```

So that you could write

```
h = g `on3` f
```

There may be a way to write `on3` and `on4` in terms of `on`, but if there is I can't see it at the moment.

Answer (score 6):

You may also find Arrows interesting.  Here's one way to do it:

```
h g f a b = uncurry g ((f *** f) (a, b))
```

Which is equivalent to your example (except that `g` and `f` are not free) and `on`.  Using:

- [definition](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/src/Control-Arrow.html#&&&) of `***` for functions:

  ```
  (***) f g ~(x,y) = (f x, g y)
  ```
- [definition](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/src/Data-Tuple.html#uncurry) of `uncurry`:

  ```
  uncurry f p =  f (fst p) (snd p)
  ```

And substituting them into the original equation:

1. `h g f a b = uncurry g (f a, f b)`  *(used `***` definition)*
2. `h g f a b = g (f a) (f b)` *(used `uncurry` definition)*